# windows registry issue installing bugzilla

Tags: perl, apache2, bugzilla

I am trying to install Bugzilla on Windows 7 but I am not able to install it as described in [*Teach Apache About Bugzilla*](http://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/apache-windows.html#teach-apache-about-bugzilla). In the instructions it asks to edit Windows registry and create

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cgi\Shell\ExecCGI\Command
```

But I don't have `.cgi\Shell\ExecCGI\Command` key in my registry. I have checked my friends computer also, but he doesn't have that key in the registry either.

I have downloaded the Bugzilla source code and all Perl modules. I have been searching for a solution for two days now.

Answer (score 2):

That document asks you to *create* the registry key. You do it like this in regedit

- Right-click on `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Select `New`, `Key` and name the key `.cgi`
- Right-click on the new key `.cgi`. Select `New`, `Key` and name the key `Shell`
- Right-click on the new key `Shell`. Select `New`, `Key` and name the key `ExecCGI`
- Right-click on the new key `ExecCGI`. Select `New`, `String Value` and name the value `Command`
- Edit the string value to the poath to your Perl executable

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect you to already have `.cgi` extension defined unless the machine had previously been used as a Web server with CGI support.  Anyway, you are adding a new extension: just create each level as a `Right-Click > New > Key` as needed.

Alternatively, you can make a `cgi.reg` file and double-click on it; here's what it should look like:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.cgi\Shell\ExceCGI\Command]
@="C:\\Perl\\bin\\perl.exe -T"
```

All the missing Keys will be created as well.  (Don't forget to alter the path as necessary.)